# Dynamically Populate LoopupRows()

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup, loop

How could I retrieve values from several columns that are in a row and there various combination of values (key1 = col1, col4, col5), (key2 = col3, col5), (key3 = col3)

I have a Data Extension with several Columns and I want to see what column has the lowest number for a key.

```
KEY    |    Col1    |    Col2    |    Col3    |    Col4    |    Col5   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 key1        5            10            2            3            0
 key2        8             1            5            4            2
 key3        0             0            0            5            1
```

Now I want to retrieve the values of columns that are specified with each key

I used the LookupRows() but am stuck on how to iterate through the column parameter.

Example:

```
SET @key1 = col1, col4, col5

SET @key1 = BuildRowsetFromString(@key1,",")
// key1 now has the array of col1, col4, col5

FOR @i = 1 to RowCount(@key1) DO
SET @row = (Row(@key1, @i)
SET @keyvalues = Field(@row,1) 
SET @key1Values = LookupRows("Data Extension", @keyvalues, "KEY", @key)
// I need @keyvalues to loop through the various columns with each iteration so it would pass on the first iteration col1, col4 on the 2nd and so on.

NEXT @i
```

Ultimately I want to be able to use the output to create statements

```
 if (@keyvalues != 0 || @keyvalues == 1) THEN
Do Something
ENDIF
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer in this post might help you with looping through rows and columns, take a look: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/147954/17546